# CSV file is not downloading in asp.net because Respose.Write isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, webforms

I'm creating a CSV file with `StringBuilder`and I'm trying to download the file with the following code:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.csv");
Response.Charset = "utf-8";
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

I'been using this same code in other projects with no problem, but in this one when I click the `Export button` the code is executed but nothing happens, no exception, no error, nothing.

Also try the following: `Response.Write(sb.ToString());`
And `"application/text"` or `application/csv`

Anyone can point me in the right direction to make it work?

## UPDATE

For some reason that I don't understand yet, `Response.Output.Write` or `Response.Write` are not working because I can't get anything, not even a single string or javascript alert.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
Response.Flush();
```

because your `Response.Buffer = true`.

And Use

```
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: Still the same, nothing happens

Comment: Apparently  `Response.Output.Write` or `Response.Write` are not working for some reason because I can't get anything, not even a single string or javascript alert.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.This code will work for you :

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=YourFileName.csv");
Response.Charset = "utf-8";
Response.ContentType = "application/text";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
{YourControlId}.RenderControl(hw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: Still the same, apparently  `Response.Output.Write` or `Response.Write` are not working for some reason because I can't get anything, not even a single string or javascript alert.

Comment: Have you surrounded your code with try-catch block and check if there was an exception raised?